# To remove newlines after empty line

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl, tr

Data

```
4. Alendronic acid
A. Antiosteoporotic agent. 
B. Inhibit osteoclast formation and function by inhibiting FPPS enzyme, so increase bone mass. 
C. Osteoporosis in combination with vitamin D. 

5. Aminophylline
A. Methylxanthine. Less potent and shorter-acting bronchodilator than Theophylline. 
B. Phosphodiesterase (PDE) inhibitor, so increase cAMP so affecting calcium so relaxes respiratory SM and dilates bronchi/bronchioles. 
C. Last option of asthma attack, COPD, Reversible airways obstruction.
```

which I want to be (and later without the empty line as in the pseudocode below explained)

```
4. Alendronic acid
A. Antiosteoporotic agent. B. Inhibit osteoclast formation and function by inhibiting FPPS enzyme, so increase bone mass. C. Osteoporosis in combination with vitamin D. 

5. Aminophylline
A. Methylxanthine. Less potent and shorter-acting bronchodilator than Theophylline. B. Phosphodiesterase (PDE) inhibitor, so increase cAMP so affecting calcium so relaxes respiratory SM and dilates bronchi/bronchioles. C. Last option of asthma attack, COPD, Reversible airways obstruction.
```

My attempt was originally based on the idea of removing all empty lines by `gsed -n "s/^$//;t;p;"` but this is not possible now.

Pseudocode

- remove all newlines (not empty lines) by `tr '\n' ' '` (everything now one liners but problem since takes also empty lines!)
- replace all *A.* by *\nA.* by `sed 's#A.#\nA.#'`
- remove all empty lines by `gsed -n "s/^$//;t;p;"`

Pseudocode in summary

```
cat                                 \
     10.6.2015.tex                  \
                                    \
| tr '\n' ' '                       \
                                    \
| sed 's#A.#\nA.#'                  \
                                    \
| gsed -n "s/^$//;t;p;"             \
                                    \
> 10.6.2015_quizlet.tex
```

which is however wrong because of the logical mistake in the first line.

How can remove newlines after empty line in Perl/Sed/tr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use perl or awk to read the data a paragraph at a time, and remove all but the first newline:

```
perl -00 -pe '$\="\n\n"; s/\n/\0/; s/\n//g; s/\0/\n/' file
```

Commented

```
perl -00 -pe '   # each record is separated by blank lines (-00)
                 # read the file a record at a time and auto-print (-p)
    $\="\n\n";   # auto-append 2 newlines to each record
    s/\n/\0/;    # turn the first newline into a null byte
    s/\n//g;     # remove all other newlines
    s/\0/\n/     # restore the first newline
' file
```

Similarly

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{print $1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s", $i; print ""; print ""}' file
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because I like the idea of reading in the data first as blocks and then processing, simplifying much the task.

Comment: @Masi; Note that such *block definition* is also part of the `awk` solution (with `RS=""`). (I added an explanation.)

Comment: @Janis - I think they all do. Well, ok, there's another `sed` here that does a `s///`ubstitution `t`est loop - which I guess would depend on how you define *block*. I personally prefer to block the edits to manageable globally applied sizes whenever possible. `sed`'s pattern/hold spaces can handle at least 4k.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sed '/[0-9]\./{n;:l;N;/\n$/!s/\n/ /;t l}' file
```

This will output:

```
4. Alendronic acid
A. Antiosteoporotic agent.  B. Inhibit osteoclast formation and function by inhibiting FPPS enzyme, so increase bone mass.  C. Osteoporosis in combination with vitamin D. 

5. Aminophylline
A. Methylxanthine. Less potent and shorter-acting bronchodilator than Theophylline.  B. Phosphodiesterase (PDE) inhibitor, so increase cAMP so affecting calcium so relaxes respiratory SM and dilates bronchi/bronchioles.  C. Last option of asthma attack, COPD, Reversible airways obstruction.
```

**Explanation**

We match the line with the number and the period with `/[0-9]\./`. Then we enter a code block, that goes to the next line with `n`. It starts a loop with `:l`, that appends the next line with `N`, and replaces the newline with a space with `s/\n/ /`. The loop terminates when it reaches an empty line, which is picked up by the condition `/\n$/!`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` solution that solves the issue by appropriate definitions of what's the field and record separators for input and output; thus the effective command (`$1=$1 FS`) is quite simple:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { RS="" ; FS="\n" ; OFS="" ; ORS="\n\n" }
  $1=$1 FS
'
```

**Explanation:**

`RS=""` - will handle blocks of empty line separated data as one record

`FS="\n"` - will define each line of a block as an own addressable field

`OFS=""` - due to blank terminated data no output field separator necessary

`ORS="\n\n"` - to separate the new blocks (as the input data) by a blank line

`$1=$1 FS` - the first field (i.e. first line) will be separated from the rest of the lines in the block by a newline character; as that assignment is a true condition in `awk` the modified record (block) will be printed

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]/!H;//x;$x;s/\n\([^A]\)/ \1/gp' <infile >outfile
```

Seems to do the trick:

1. `/^[0-9]/!H`

   - If a line does `!`not begin with a digit, then append it to `H`old space following a `\n`ewline.
2. `//x;$x`

   - If it does begin with a digit, and/or if this is the `$`last line, e`x`change pattern and `h`old spaces.
3. `s/\n\([^A]\)/ \1/gp`

   - If 1 or more sequences of a `\n`ewline followed by any not-*A* character can be found in pattern space, then `g`lobally `s///`ubstitute the `\n`ewlines in those sequences for a *<space>* and `p`rint the results.
   - The only time a `\n`ewline will be found is immediately following an e`x`change - so only on the lines beginning with a digit or the last line.
   - The leading digit gets to retain its `\n`ewline because the separating line is the *last* character in pattern space when the e`x`change occurs - and so there is no `\([^A]\)` character to follow it, and so it does not get `s///`ubstituted for a space.

And that's all.

#### OUTPUT:

```
4. Alendronic acid
A. Antiosteoporotic agent.  B. Inhibit osteoclast formation and function by inhibiting FPPS enzyme, so increase bone mass.  C. Osteoporosis in combination with vitamin D. 

5. Aminophylline
A. Methylxanthine. Less potent and shorter-acting bronchodilator than Theophylline.  B. Phosphodiesterase (PDE) inhibitor, so increase cAMP so affecting calcium so relaxes respiratory SM and dilates bronchi/bronchioles.  C. Last option of asthma attack, COPD, Reversible airways obstruction.
```