# How can I replace all semicolons after 1st one?

Tags: text-processing, perl

This problem is related to my attempt to import questions and their answers in a Excel file into .txt -file which Anki flashcard program handles as described [here](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#importing).
I cannot have more than 2 fields so I need to make options one field.

Data stored as CSV from LibreOffice (semicolon as field separator - only distinction what the manual says) as instructed in Anki manual

```
Question ipsun; option 1 ; option 2 ; option 3 ; option 4 ; ... ; option n
Question ipsun; option 1 ; option 2 ; option 3 ; option 4 ; ... ; option n
...
```

where each entry with all options is in one line i.e. one "flashcard". In one card, front-part before semicolon, and back-part after semicolon. Second flashcard in newline and so on.

Wanted output which should be in UTF-8

```
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
...
```

My pseudocode in Perl based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208363/16920)

```
perl -00 -pe s/;/\0/; s/;/ |/g; s/\0/;/' file
```

Commented

```
perl -00 -pe '   # each record is separated by blank lines (-00)
                 # read the file a record at a time and auto-print (-p)
    s/;/\0/;    # turn the first semicolon into a null byte
    s/;/ |/g;     # replace all other semicolons with " |"
    s/\0/;/     # restore the first semicolon
' file
```

How can you replace all semicolons after 1st semicolon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 'y/|;/\n|/;s/|/;/;y/\n/|/' <<\IN
Question ipsun; option 1 ; option 2 ; option 3 ; option 4 ; ... ; option n
IN
```

Note that this does *not* use a regexp to handle the majority of the replacements, but rather uses a more basic *(and far more performant)* *translation* function to do so - and does so in a POSIX portable fashion. This should work on any machine with a POSIX `sed` installed.

It translates `;` semicolons to `|` pipes and `|` pipes to `\n`ewlines simultaneously. The `|` pipes are set aside as `\n`ewlines in case any occur on an input line. It then `s///`ubstitutes the first occurring `|` pipe for a `;` semicolon, and then translates all `\n`ewlines to `|` pipes - thus restoring any it might have set aside to robustly handle the single  `s///`ubstitution.

While I use a `<<\IN` here-document for the sake of copy/pastable demonstration, you should probably use `<infile >outfile`.

#### OUTPUT:

```
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
```

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `sed`​:

```
sed 's/;/|/2g'
```

Which globally replaces `;` with `|` starting from the 2nd occurrence.

While `sed 's/;/|/2` and `s/;/|/g` are POSIX, the combination is not and the behaviour varies across implementations. With the GNU implementation of `sed` however, the behaviour is clearly documented.

Comment: This looks great! Can you please explain this `/2g`? Globally after second replacement. Is this efficient operation? I do not understand how you can build so short option efficiently. Can you, please, also compare this to Mikeserv's answer. Your is much more readable. How are they different etc?

Comment: @Masi, mikeserv's is portable, this one's shorter and more efficient with GNU `sed`. I'd go with mikeserv's unless you know your code or any copy of it will never end-up on a non-GNU system. Performance is probably not an issue unless your input is several megabytes

Comment: I am studying this command more here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209086/16920 Interested in how you can extend it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how it's handled? I've come to believe `//` works out under the hood to something like a call to `regexec()` after `/address/` calls `regcomp()`, but the `s///[num]g` confuses me in that context - would it work by doing both for one?

Answer (score 4):

Simply `sed -e 's/;/|/g' -e 's/|/;/' data.csv` gets you:

```
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
```

Which looks like what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You made a slight mistake:

```
~$ perl -00 -pe 's/;/\0/; s/;/\n/g; s/\0/;/' file
Question; option 1
 option 2
 option 3
 option 4
 ...
 option n
```

what you have done:

```
s/;//g;     # remove all other semicolons
s/\0/;/     # restore the first semicolon
```

what you stated you want:

```
s/;/\n/g;     # change all other semicolons
s/\0/;/     # restore the first semicolon
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't notice an `awk` version, so here it is:

`awk -F';'  '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)gsub(" ; "," | ");print}' testfile1.txt`

Output example:

```
$ cat testfile1.txt                                                                                
Question ipsun; option 1 ; option 2 ; option 3 ; option 4 ; ... ; option n
Question ipsun; option 1 ; option 2 ; option 3 ; option 4 ; ... ; option n

$ awk -F';'  '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)gsub(" ; "," | ");print}' testfile1.txt                           
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
Question ipsun; option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 | ... | option n
```