# Search word preceded by Name in Sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

This thread is motivated by the arithmetic command found in the link of this thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209095/16920) in Sed.
So I would like to do backward arithmetic in Sed.

Data

```
Mikael symptom
David symptom
hello symptom
```

Command should return the first two entries. 
Look-behind in Perl is one approach, but I would like to see if this can be done with Sed.

One approach in pseudocode

- Match names: words in `g/[A-Z]\w\w/`; `is.words[2]('symptom')`

Look-behind

- Match `symptom`; lookbehind Name. Return if Name.

Can you do this pseudocode in Sed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. You want the first two lines of the data? The names before the word `symptom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\{1,\} symptom$/!d
    H;x;/^\n/!q;s///;x;d'
```

This will look for lines beginning with an uppercase char followed by one or more lower case chars then only a *<space>* and the string *symptom*. If the current line doesn't match it is `d`eleted and the script starts anew from the top w/ the next input line.

If it *does* match it is copied to `H`old space following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter. The first time this happens `h`old space will be empty - an so the leading character will be a `\n`ewline. After the matching line is `H`eld, the `h`old and pattern spaces are e`x`changed. If there is `!`*not* a leading `\n`ewline in pattern space at that time then `sed` `q`uits input - abruptly ceasing to read any more input *(or execute any more commands in its script - such as `d`)* at all. But when there is the leading `\n`ewline is removed and `h`old and pattern spaces are once again e`x`changed and pattern space is `d`eleted.

The result is the first the line is encountered it is held and its signifying first occurrence marker saves it from `q`uitting input, but the *second* time it happens ends processing.

But maybe I misunderstood? I understood you to mean you wanted only the first two matches in a file.

If you only want the *Name* if *symptom$* that's way easy:

```
sed -n '/^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\{1,\} [^ ]*$/s/ symptom$//p'
```

Here we just verify that we're definitely looking at a *likely* matching line before ever even attempting a `s///`ubstitution - because the `s///`ubstitution is a *function* of the parent address. If true, we attempt to trim the unwanted tail way and only `p`rint if successful - so *both* head and tail of line conditions are verified before we do.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to print any line that contains a capitalized word immediately followed by the word `symptom`.  In that case:

```
$ sed -rn '/\b[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*[[:space:]]+symptom/p' data
Mikael symptom
David symptom
```

For convenience, I have used `\b` which signifies word boundary.  This is at least supported by GNU sed.  Let me know if your sed does not support it.

#### How it works:

The basic form is:

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' file
```

This prints only lines that match `pattern`.  In our case, the pattern consists of:

- `\b`

  This matches only at a word boundary.
- `[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*`

  This matches an upper case letter followed by zero or more lower case letters.

  Note that, in olden times, this might have been written `[A-Z][a-z]+`.  Because of unicode, that is now unreliable.  The above uses character classes `upper` and `lower` and consequently is unicode safe.
- `[[:space:]]+symptom`

  This matches one or more spaces followed by the word `symptom`.

#### Alternative

Suppose that you only wanted to print the names that precede `symptom`:

```
$ sed -rn 's/\b([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)[[:space:]]+symptom.*/\1/p' data
Mikael
David
```

Comment: `[[:space:]]` matches `\r` `\f` `\t` `\n` as well as a literal space char in the C locale.

Comment: `\n` does not naturally occur in a sed pattern space.  Since tabs are often visually similar to the literal space character, including it seems to be a strong advantage and is, in fact, why I used a character class instead of a literal space.  If the concern is that (a) stray `\r` or `\f` might occur in the input __and__ that (b) such characters should not be considered a valid word separator, then we should use `[[:blank:]]` in place of `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: tabs are not spaces. I generally prefer not to make such assumptions for others and their data. And anyway, In the UTF-8 locale it also matches the non-breaking space, I believe.

Comment: Your preferences are noted.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^[[:upper:]]\w* symptom/s/ .*//p'
```

print lines which starts by capitalized word with `symptom` after it and everything but fist word removed.

Comment: It will print `[A-Z][_A-Za-z0-9]*` in the C locale, and it will do so even when input is `[^ ]+ symptom some other junk...`